# Running out of I2C channels on microcontroller

Tags: sensor, i2c

I am building a signal acquisition system that has a lot of sensor. These sensors communicate with the microcontroller by I2C interface. I'm running out of I2C channels on the microcontroller. Is there a way that I can add more sensor on the mcu withing necessary using I2C channels? Like by using GIOP?

Comment: How many sensors? Can the sensors be configured for different I2C addresses? Can you share the datasheet for the sensor?

Comment: Abed Paulus - Can you please edit the question and clarify these parts: (a) The sentence mentioning "withing necessary using I2C channels" isn't clear. Do you mean something like "without using additional I2C buses"? Or something else? (b) You mention "GIOP". Is that something specific to your MCU? Or did you mean the general term "GPIO"? (c) There are several previous questions which explain things like using multiple sensors with the same I2C address. How did they *not* answer your problem? (Also, please include answers to the previous comment, by adding details into the question). Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally any GPIO pins on a micro-controller can be used for an I2C master interface, but you may have to write "bit-bang" code to do this.
Another option is to use an I2C multiplexer chip.

Comment: Why did you put multiplexer chip _after_ bit-banging? Especially considering OP mentions "a lot of sensors", which no bit-banging can support, unless running at abysmal clock rate or working with one sensor at a time.